# PySide QFileDialog.getOpenFileName do not return file name

Tags: python, qt, dialog, pyside

Need Help with PySide: 
Hello, currently i'm learning PySide and Qt. Now i have a problem with the QFileDialog.getOpenFileName Method on OS X.

When i use this code:

```
file_object = 
    QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Text File", 
                                dir=".", filter="Text Files (*.txt)")

print file_object
```

The result is

```
(u"", Text Files (*.txt))
```

So there is no return value for the a selected text file.

When i use this code:

```
file_object = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Text File", 
                                          dir=".", filter="Text Files (*.txt)",
                                          options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

print file_object
```

The result is as expected:

```
(u'/temp/example.txt', u'Text Files (*.txt)')
```

I would like to use the native FileDialog but it seems that there is a bug in Pyside or Qt or maybe i use the API wrong?

Thx for help﻿

Comment: You should probably say what versions of pyside, qt and osx you are using. It's probably a bug in qt. What happens if you use `getOpenFileName` with no arguments at all?